# Sending Tether USDT via ethereum RPC JSON API to another Tether wallet

Tags: ethereum, rpc, tether

I'm trying to send tether from one eth account with ether only to another one via rpc json api.

This is my account: 
https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0xbe9027e5d76df40e51300a49aea6152e0c885eb1

```
{
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"id":"personal_sendTransaction_1562579177",
"method":"personal_sendTransaction",
"params":[{
    "from":"0xbe9027e5d76df40e51300a49aea6152e0c885eb1",
    "to":"0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
    "value":"0x0",
    "data":"0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000CfCB8f60D94827381b4BDa53f052aAFEC246D72e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dbba0"
  },
  "password"
 ]
}
```

This is the result

```
{"code":-32000, "message":"insufficient funds for gas * price + value"}
```

But I definitely have some USDT there.
Also, which amount should I provide in data? in USDT or in ETH?

What could be a possible solution for this issue?

Comment: DId you success? Who to get "data" ?

Comment: Yes, I succeed. In data should be amount in USDT and source wallet should also have enough ETH to pay the fee

Comment: @RomanBattlez how did you encode source address and amount in the data field?

Answer (score 0):

Wallet should have ETH on it too to pay the gas

Comment: Correct, ETH network needs gas to update it on blockchain.